# How do I add AppService IAM Roles to access_token for Managed Identity in Azure?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to use Managed Identities to authenticate and authorize endpoints on a controller of an API hosted in Azure (single-tenant).

Via the Azure portal, I have the IAM roles defined on the target AppService and have assigned the roles to the managed identity I'm using.  I also have the managed identity assigned to the calling application.  Is there a way I can have these IAM roles appear in the token retrieved by the identity_endpoint that is created with the inclusion of the managed identity?

I've tried doing this with an app registration using app roles and I've tried using the IAM roles directly on the AppService and haven't been able to come up with a working combination.

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit: Adding image of role assignment that doesn't seem to have gone as intended:
[App Role Assignment missing Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wNf1.png)
[Role id source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhxrT.png)

Comment: Are these Azure management roles that you are referring to? Like can you assign them through the Access control tab of the resource?

Comment: yes @juunas, those are exactly the ones I mean!  I have the managed identities assigned to custom roles via the Access control (IAM) tab of the target resource, and have the managed identities assigned to the Identity tab of the calling resource.  Thanks.

Comment: To me it sounds like you might be using the wrong thing then. If you want to call your API, you need to use App roles in Azure AD, not management RBAC roles. I have an article on this topic actually: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions

Comment: Hey @juunas, thanks so much for taking the time to respond.  I followed the steps but for some reason the role assignment doesn't seem to have gone as planned after executing the powershell command. I've attached screenshots in the main post.  The correct MI was made a user of the correct App service principal, but the role from the manifest does not display as assigned.  Instead, it shows no role assigned.  Do you have any experience with this issue?  The blacked out guid in the second image is the value i used for id in the powershell command to represent the role for the two assignments.

Comment: Did you check the application (where the app roles are registered) in Enterprise applications tab? If you go there to Permissions, can you see the Managed Identity principals and the roles?

Comment: No, I cannot see the principals mapped to the roles in the Permissions view :/

Comment: Thank for your responses @juunas.  Do you happen to have a blog post on how to use that token to authorize actions based on the role coming through?  I thought I had everything set up for once the token contained the role, but I'm still getting unauthorized.